# Shorthand Addition Operator together with Shorthand If/Else - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addition, shorthand

is it possibile to use the shorthand of addition/subtraction operator `number += 1`
and the shorthand of if / else `number = (true ? 1 : 0);` together?

The condition should decide the addition or the subtraction.

Such like this: `number = (true ? +=1 : -=1);`

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that *adding* a *negative* number subtracts that number? You should think about the problem this way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
number += 1 * (condition ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: @FelixKling negative, for subtraction.

Comment: @Joseph: Uh? `1 * -1 == -1` and `1 * 1 == 1`... I don't see what the `1 *` is needed for. `number + (1 * -1)` is the same as `number + (-1)`.

Comment: say `n = 5`, then lets add or subtract 3, so `n+= (-3) or (3)` depending on the condition. that's how i see it though.

Comment: @Joseph: Ah, I see now... an example with another number would have been better. E.g. your `-3` and `3` example, would have become `1 * (condition ? 3 : -3)` for me (`1 *` is unnecessary), whereas you see it as `3 * (condition ? 1 : -1)`. This is not about which way is better, I was just confused. Interesting in which different ways such a little thing can be interpreted :)

Comment: @FelixKling i really must be sleepy. how did i just miss that. XD

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `+=` operator you need to have the variable declared in first place, otherwise can't work. If you have it, then you can simple have:

```
number += condition ? 1 : -1;
```

Notice that if you have just the number `1` and `-1`, and `condition` is boolean, you could do something like:

```
number += +condition || -1;
```

To be precise, something that returns `1` for `true` and something else for `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and have the effect of adding or subtracting an operation

```
var number = 0;
number += (condition) ? (1 * (<operation>)) : (-1 * (<operation>));
```